# How to operate sd module in esp32?

Tags: c++, memory, arduino, esp32, platformio

I am new using microcontrollers and I am testing the operation of the example code of the platformio id to create a file in an sd, but when I compile it after passing it to ESP32, it throws me the error that appears in the image "Make sure SD card lines have pull-up resistors in place esp32". Is it a code problem or do I need to add some resistance to the connection?
I leave an image of how it is connected 
Thanks

```
  /* SD card and FAT filesystem example.
   This example code is in the Public Domain (or CC0 licensed, at your option.)

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, this
   software is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR
   CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include "esp_err.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "esp_vfs_fat.h"
#include "driver/sdmmc_host.h"
#include "driver/sdspi_host.h"
#include "sdmmc_cmd.h"

static const char *TAG = "example";

// This example can use SDMMC and SPI peripherals to communicate with SD card.
// By default, SDMMC peripheral is used.
// To enable SPI mode, uncomment the following line:

// #define USE_SPI_MODE

// When testing SD and SPI modes, keep in mind that once the card has been
// initialized in SPI mode, it can not be reinitialized in SD mode without
// toggling power to the card.

#ifdef USE_SPI_MODE
// Pin mapping when using SPI mode.
// With this mapping, SD card can be used both in SPI and 1-line SD mode.
// Note that a pull-up on CS line is required in SD mode.
#define PIN_NUM_MISO 2
#define PIN_NUM_MOSI 15
#define PIN_NUM_CLK  14
#define PIN_NUM_CS   13
#endif //USE_SPI_MODE

void app_main(void)
{
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Initializing SD card");

#ifndef USE_SPI_MODE
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Using SDMMC peripheral");
    sdmmc_host_t host = SDMMC_HOST_DEFAULT();

    // To use 1-line SD mode, uncomment the following line:
    // host.flags = SDMMC_HOST_FLAG_1BIT;

    // This initializes the slot without card detect (CD) and write protect (WP) signals.
    // Modify slot_config.gpio_cd and slot_config.gpio_wp if your board has these signals.
    sdmmc_slot_config_t slot_config = SDMMC_SLOT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();

    // GPIOs 15, 2, 4, 12, 13 should have external 10k pull-ups.
    // Internal pull-ups are not sufficient. However, enabling internal pull-ups
    // does make a difference some boards, so we do that here.
    gpio_set_pull_mode(15, GPIO_PULLUP_ONLY);   // CMD, needed in 4- and 1- line modes
    gpio_set_pull_mode(2, GPIO_PULLUP_ONLY);    // D0, needed in 4- and 1-line modes
    gpio_set_pull_mode(4, GPIO_PULLUP_ONLY);    // D1, needed in 4-line mode only
    gpio_set_pull_mode(12, GPIO_PULLUP_ONLY);   // D2, needed in 4-line mode only
    gpio_set_pull_mode(13, GPIO_PULLUP_ONLY);   // D3, needed in 4- and 1-line modes

#else
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Using SPI peripheral");

    sdmmc_host_t host = SDSPI_HOST_DEFAULT();
    sdspi_slot_config_t slot_config = SDSPI_SLOT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
    slot_config.gpio_miso = PIN_NUM_MISO;
    slot_config.gpio_mosi = PIN_NUM_MOSI;
    slot_config.gpio_sck  = PIN_NUM_CLK;
    slot_config.gpio_cs   = PIN_NUM_CS;
    // This initializes the slot without card detect (CD) and write protect (WP) signals.
    // Modify slot_config.gpio_cd and slot_config.gpio_wp if your board has these signals.
#endif //USE_SPI_MODE

    // Options for mounting the filesystem.
    // If format_if_mount_failed is set to true, SD card will be partitioned and
    // formatted in case when mounting fails.
    esp_vfs_fat_sdmmc_mount_config_t mount_config = {
        .format_if_mount_failed = false,
        .max_files = 5
    };

    // Use settings defined above to initialize SD card and mount FAT filesystem.
    // Note: esp_vfs_fat_sdmmc_mount is an all-in-one convenience function.
    // Please check its source code and implement error recovery when developing
    // production applications.
    sdmmc_card_t* card;
    esp_err_t ret = esp_vfs_fat_sdmmc_mount("/sdcard", &host, &slot_config, &mount_config, &card);

    if (ret != ESP_OK) {
        if (ret == ESP_FAIL) {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to mount filesystem. "
                "If you want the card to be formatted, set format_if_mount_failed = true.");
        } else {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to initialize the card (%d). "
                "Make sure SD card lines have pull-up resistors in place.", ret);
        }
        return;
    }

    // Card has been initialized, print its properties
    sdmmc_card_print_info(stdout, card);

    // Use POSIX and C standard library functions to work with files.
    // First create a file.
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Opening file");
    FILE* f = fopen("/sdcard/hello.txt", "w");
    if (f == NULL) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to open file for writing");
        return;
    }
    fprintf(f, "Hello %s!\n", card->cid.name);
    fclose(f);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "File written");

    // Check if destination file exists before renaming
    struct stat st;
    if (stat("/sdcard/foo.txt", &st) == 0) {
        // Delete it if it exists
        unlink("/sdcard/foo.txt");
    }

    // Rename original file
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Renaming file");
    if (rename("/sdcard/hello.txt", "/sdcard/foo.txt") != 0) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Rename failed");
        return;
    }

    // Open renamed file for reading
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Reading file");
    f = fopen("/sdcard/foo.txt", "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to open file for reading");
        return;
    }
    char line[64];
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), f);
    fclose(f);
    // strip newline
    char* pos = strchr(line, '\n');
    if (pos) {
        *pos = '\0';
    }
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Read from file: '%s'", line);

    // All done, unmount partition and disable SDMMC or SPI peripheral
    esp_vfs_fat_sdmmc_unmount();
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Card unmounted");
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKwZi.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEowP.png)

Comment: Please include **your code** in the question, not the library that you used. Most likely you need to add pull-up resistors in the the circuit, as the error states. At that point this is not a programming question.  The ESP32 does have an SD card interface, but I do not think it is available in Arduino code.

Comment: First **Make sure** that your wiring is OK and SD have the proper format and tested. I can't see the error code for `esp_vfs_fat_sdmmc_mount` in your terminal. Can you print it on a separate line and give us the code for better help.

Comment: @Strom hi , It this the project example that give me platformio for test SD , the SD hase formated in FAT 32

Comment: @M. R. the code that I am using is that I attach, I do not distinguish if it is a library, it is the first work that I have to do of this type and I still do not know and c ++ I only handle the basics, sorry; and as for the error I think it would be the last line of the image is everything that came out in the terminal, try to try something apart later

Answer (score 0):

"Make sure SD card lines have pull-up resistors in place." is the default error message when communication with the SD Card (module) does not work.

```
esp_err_t ret = esp_vfs_fat_sdmmc_mount("/sdcard", &host, &slot_config, &mount_config, &card);

if (ret != ESP_OK) {
    if (ret == ESP_FAIL) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to mount filesystem. "
            "If you want the card to be formatted, set format_if_mount_failed = true.");
    } else {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to initialize the card (%d). "
            "Make sure SD card lines have pull-up resistors in place.", ret);
    }
    return;
}
```

The information about the pull-up resistors is only a hint what might be wrong similar to: Maybe one of your wires is not connected correctly.

I had the same error when I tried that code using an SD-Card module with SPI connection which I used previously with Arduino.

After trying lots of things and looking at info all over the internet it seems to me that this never worked with SPI and an SD-Card module which uses SPI. I remember I found info like "this will be implemented later" but I don't remember where I read that.

Later I found there are other SD-Card modules which don't use SPI.

I used this one and it worked.

[image: 9 Pin Micro SD TF Card Reader Read & Write Module]
https://www.ebay.com/itm/9-Pin-Micro-SD-TF-Card-Reader-Read-Write-Module-Storage-Board-Memory-Arduino/401316600781

This is not connected with SPI and that option has to be selected in the code here:

```
// This example can use SDMMC and SPI peripherals to communicate with SD card.
// By default, SDMMC peripheral is used.
// To enable SPI mode, uncomment the following line:

//#define USE_SPI_MODE
```

And later in the code there is this section:

```
// To use 1-line SD mode, uncomment the following line:
host.flags = SDMMC_HOST_FLAG_1BIT;
```

I was able to get it running by using the 1BIT mode with above module.
I didn't get it running using all connections (I think that is called SD Mode or 1 Line SD Mode).